# Modifying first pivot to median pivot for quicksort trouble

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I'm very stuck on something that should be trivial. I'm trying to modify code that uses the first index as a pivot in quicksort, to code that uses the median. My professor said the easiest way to go about doing this would be to send the median value to the first index, and send the first index value to the median index. I'm trying to do this at the top of the code but whenever I run it for an average array, I get an out of bounds exception.

[My code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTAdN.png)

Sorry, I'm working on my ipad in VI so taking a picture is easier for me.

Comment: I recommend to paste your code as text to allow others copy it and compile.

Comment: A PNG of your code? Really?

Comment: You cannot copy&paste a text file on a IPad???